# Maximum pressure of a rubber balloon

Tags: pressure

I've had a question about this topic previously, but the material was inelastic.

[Forces in a balloon popping?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/92089/forces-in-a-balloon-popping)

What happens when a material is non-hookian?

Say rubber,

I've found this pdf on the web:
http://www.researchgate.net/publication/245382031_Inflating_a_Rubber_Balloon